# QtCreator: An issue with the issues tab

Tags: qt-creator

I am working on a rather large code base, so I created several sessions to sort it a little bit.

In all sessions but one the "issues" tab works as designed and everything is fine.

Only in this one session it does not work and no compiler errors or warnings make it into the issues tab.

My colleagues have no idea, google and stackoverflow give no real answer (yet), so I have to ask.

I am using `QtCreator 4.1.0` under `Ubuntu 14.04`, cmake is version `3.7.0-rc2`, 
and clang++ says: `Ubuntu clang version 3.5.0-4ubuntu2~trusty2 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)`

Any ideas??